# Problem loading ASP.NET report in iFrame with Internet Explorer

Tags: asp.net, html, internet-explorer, iframe

I have seen multiple posts and websites regarding this issue, yet none of the solutions / workarounds posted have worked for me. I am trying to load an ASP.NET report into an iFrame. The iFrame will load correctly (across all browsers), but when I run the report, Internet Explorer only will show the following error:

> ASP.NET session has expired

I have tried to use an HTML form to POST and target the iframe, as the workaround suggests here: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/561066/reportviewer-2010-iframe-internet-explorer

I have also tried adding the following to the web.config file of the report application:

```
<sessionState  
       mode="InProc"
       stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424"
       sqlConnectionString="data source=127.0.0.1;Trusted_Connection=yes"
       cookieless="false"  
       timeout="20"  
/>
```

I have also tried to set my server to use InProc mode, and that still does nothing. Can anyone offer any other potential solutions that they may know about?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I got it.

The "cookieless" parameter must be set to "true":

```
<sessionState  
       mode="InProc"
       stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424"
       sqlConnectionString="data source=127.0.0.1;Trusted_Connection=yes"
       cookieless="true"  
       timeout="120"  
   />
```